# Пожалуйста, помогите оптимизировать нечитабельный участок кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предыстория к коду: есть файл xlsx, в котором находятся объединенные ячейки, но объединены они криво, там где не нужно они объединены, там где нужно - могут быть обычными. Я решил, что легче взять просто всё строчки из этого файла, которые мне нужны, а значения None (None будут появляться, т.к. в объединенных ячейках заполняется лишь первая, крайняя левая), буду преобразовывать к прошлому значению, которое было известно. Всё это отрабатывает как нужно, теперь к коду:

```
mvz_list = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7']
filials = ['Краснодар', 'Краснодар', 'Краснодар', 'Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Сочи', 'Владимир', 'Владимир', 'Владимир']
list_of_all_used_values = []

for i, value_mvz in enumerate(mvz_list):
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(f'Берем {value_mvz}')
    list_for_one_filial = []
    counter = 1
    if value_mvz not in list_of_all_used_values:
        list_of_all_used_values.append(value_mvz)
        list_for_one_filial.append(value_mvz)
        for i2 in range(len(mvz_list[i+1:])):
            if filials[i] == filials[i+counter]:
                if mvz_list[i + counter] not in list_of_all_used_values:
                    list_for_one_filial.append(mvz_list[i + counter])
                    list_of_all_used_values.append(mvz_list[i + counter])
                    counter+=1
            else:
                counter+=1
        print(f'Временный список для филиала {filials[i]}: {list_for_one_filial}')
        print(f'Список уже использованных значений: {list_of_all_used_values}') #Принтую просто для наглядности, чтобы посмотреть, что всё работает как нужно
        print('-----------------------------------------------')


        print(f'Производим некоторые действия для "временного списка": {list_for_one_filial}')
```

Списки `mvz_list` и `filials` - это и есть то, что я получаю при парсинге Excel своим способом, описанным выше.

Далее мне необходимо перебрать списки и для каждого филиала сформировать свой временный список со всеми значениями, которые относятся только к нему. Это определяется порядковым номером в списка. Если у `mvz_list[0]` и `mvz_list[1]` одинаковые `filials[0]` и `filials[1]` - значит это нам подходит и мы добавляем оба значения к временному списку этого филиала, чтобы уже далее работать с этим временным списком.

Конкретно этот кусок кода мне совершенно не нравится, но я не знаю, как же именно лучше сделать, чтобы сохранить хоть какую-то читабельность и функциональность.
Заранее извиняюсь, что расписал целую поэму, это сделано для того, чтобы была полная картина ситуации.

Если запустите код, то принтами будет выводиться то, что я имел ввиду.

Comment: Для любого кода первое и самое главное, это понимание (что в этом случае означает описание), что он делает, т.е. какую задачу решает. Вы много написали, _как_ вы делаете что-то, но я совсем не понимаю, _что_ за задачу код решает. _Как_ код делает что-то и так видно, но вот _что_ совсем не очевидно и лично мне непонятно.

Comment: Здравствуйте, я думаю чтобы добавить читабельность необходимо добавить комментарии и перенос строки в некоторых местах, чтобы весь код не сливался в кусок байтов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так не проще будет:

```
mvz_list = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '7']
filials = ['Краснодар', 'Краснодар', 'Краснодар', 'Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Сочи', 'Владимир', 'Владимир', 'Владимир']
filial_mvz = dict()
for i in range(0, len(mvz_list) - 1):
    filial = filials[i]
    if filial in filial_mvz:
        mvz_set = filial_mvz[filial]
    else:
        mvz_set = set()
        filial_mvz[filial] = mvz_set
    mvz = mvz_list[i]
    mvz_set.add(mvz)

for filial, mvz_set in filial_mvz.items():
    list_for_one_filial = list(mvz_set)
    print(f'Временный список для филиала {filial}: {list_for_one_filial}')
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
```

?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, выглядит это уже в разы лучше, чем у меня! Благодарю Вас!